# Unable to shard an already populated collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I ran the command to shard on the collection using this command

`sh.shardCollection("db.collection_name",{"_id":"hashed"})`

I got the following error

```
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "errmsg" : "Please create an index that starts with the proposed shard key before sharding the collection",
    "code" : 72,
    "codeName" : "InvalidOptions",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1582011118, 65),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1582011118, 65),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "jOIjTJkZKkC2ZI5lFQwX4Q7QNfs=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(6774859010160984065)
        }
    }
}
```

There is already an index on `_id`

```
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.collection_name"
    }
```

I am running Mongo 4.0.0 sharded cluster setup

Comment: You have to create a Hashed index on the `_id` field. The default index on `_id`  is unique, and a hashed index _cannot_ be unique. So [Create a Hashed Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-hashed/#create-a-hashed-index) on the `_id` field (you can create one in addition to the existing one you have listed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sharding already populated collection. Then you should try :

I have database test and collection name as people. Basically you need to create an index in order to shard already populated collection. Select the key from collection and hash it

```
mongos> db.people.createIndex({ "user_id" : "hashed" }) /// 
                                    db.collection.createIndex({ "key" : "hashed"})
{
        "raw" : {
                "foo/localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27019" : {
                        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
                        "numIndexesBefore" : 4,
                        "numIndexesAfter" : 5,
                        "ok" : 1
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1593154931, 1),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1593154931, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }


mongos> sh.shardCollection("test.people", { "user_id": "hashed" })
{
        "collectionsharded" : "test.people",
        "collectionUUID" : UUID("4ee30d04-8dc9-43dc-94f6-a898bc96da89"),
        "ok" : 1,
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1593154958, 11),
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1593154958, 11),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}

mongos> sh.isBalancerRunning()
```

true

Hope it helps!!